# Terraria not working on wine

Tags: wine

hey ya i did all that but it does not launch and this appears in the terminal;

001d:err:clipboard:convert_selection Timed out waiting for SelectionNotify event 001d:err:clipboard:convert_selection Timed out waiting for SelectionNotify event Error Logging Enabled. info: Game: Terraria.exe info: DXVK: v1.7.1-2-g743f309 info: Built-in extension providers: info: Win32 WSI info: OpenVR warn: OpenVR: Failed to locate module info: Required Vulkan extension VK_KHR_surface not supported terminate called after throwing an instance of 'dxvk::DxvkError'

abnormal program termination

plz help